# Am I going about this the wrong way? What would be the ideal way to do this?

Tags: blazor-server-side, .net-5

I have a .Net 5 Blazor web app, two date pickers, and a table generating results from the date pickers. I can't seem to get the server to re-crunch the numbers and re-generate the table with input from the date pickers. Is a Blazor server app appropriate to use for this? I didn't want the massive number crunching going on in the user's browser, so I opted for Server.

```css
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-2">
        <label for="start">Start date:</label>

        <input type="date" id="start" name="range-start"
               value=@startDate
               min=@minDate max=@maxDate>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
        <label for="end">End date:</label>

        <input type="date" id="end" name="range-end"
               value=@endDate
               min=@minDate max=@maxDate>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xl-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="fetch" name="fetch-data" @onclick="GetDataAsync">Fetch data</button>
    </div>

.razor @code Portion

protected async Task GetDataAsync()
{
    rd = null;
    DateTime start, end;
    start = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Day);
    end = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Day);
    rd = await DataService1.GetDataAsync(start, end);
}
```

Some things to note from these excerpts:

1. The service is injected
2. `rd` is the data source feeding the Table
3. The service is called on page load and generates a default data set
4. Clicking the "fetch data" button doesn't seem to pass back the values from the inputs
5. Repeatedly clicking the button after the first time doesn't seem to trigger the callback/event at all

Clearly I'm new at this and could use some guidance, reading suggestions, example code. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The value of the user controls needs to have an @bind- appended to it, and the variables need a public property {get; set;} with an [Attribute] decorator instead of a private variable.

It looks like this when correct:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xl-2">
    <label for="start">Start date:</label>

    <input type="date" id="start" name="range-start"
           @bind-value=@startDate
           min=@minDate max=@maxDate>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2">
    <label for="end">End date:</label>

    <input type="date" id="end" name="range-end"
           @bind-value=@endDate
           min=@minDate max=@maxDate>
</div>
<div class="col-xl-2">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="fetch" name="fetch-data" @onclick="GetDataAsync">Fetch data</button>
</div>
```

.razor @code Portion

```
[Parameter]
public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
[Parameter]
public DateTime endDate { get; set; }

protected async Task GetDataAsync()
{
    rd = null;
    DateTime start, end;
    start = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(startDate).Day);
    end = new DateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Year, Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Month, Convert.ToDateTime(endDate).Day);
    rd = await DataService1.GetDataAsync(start, end);
}
```